# Reversing a letter replace when the alphabet has repeat letters

Tags: algorithm

I have this letter replace alphabet that I need to be able to reverse the replacements back to english. the problem is that the alphabet contains repeats, which makes changing them back ambiguous. Here's the alphabet for comparison:

a: e
b: f
c: s
d: n
e: a
f: ll
g: r
h: h
i: ai
j: sh
k: c
l: r
m: n
n: l
o: u
p: f
q: w
r: s
s: r
t: d
u: i
v: y
w: w
x: z
y: irr
z: n

As you can see, not only do several replacements use the same letter, but they aren't even all the same number of characters. How should I go about undoing the replacement?

Comment: For which programming language, and what have you tried yourself?

Comment: With the double letters, you can't really go back. As a best effort, you could try all possible variants for a word and see which one results in an english word (using an english dictionary). In case you end up with multiple valid words, you'll need some context analysis, making the problem really difficult.

Comment: The defined map is not injective, which means it cannot be reverted. Please provide more context; what are you trying to do in the bigger picture?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the way around this would be to use some sort of intermediate, delimited stage. So you could store your string along the lines of the following:

```
<root>
    <source>LanguageA</source>
    <target>LanguageB</target>
    <content> 
         [a][ll][ai]...
    </content>
</root>
```

The module which does the translation will then look into the `source` and `target` languages and using the `[` and `]` as delimiters you could go through it and convert each token (the result of this would still be a *delimited* string. Lastly you would need another module which cleans the output so that it can be rendered cleanly.